# Can there be a "span wicket:id" between the wicket:child tag in parent html page?

Tags: java, html, jboss, wicket

The example of what I want to do :

Parent HTML:

```
<wicket:child>    
 .....
 <span wicket:id="xxx"></span>  
</wicket:child>`   
...
```

Child HTML:

```
<wicket:extend>
... child content ...
</wicket:extend>
```

Supposedly when child page is opened the extend tag will replace all the content between the child tag in parent html, including the `<span wicket:id>`.

Apparently this won't work, when the child page is open error will occur:
**Wicket tags identified by wicket:id are not allowed in between `wicket:child>` and `</wicket:child>`**

I assume this is because the wicket:span tag got pass into the child extend page and cause this issue? If the span is removed the problem is resolved.

Is there anyway I can keep the span tag in paranet HTML and still make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed. Wicket components are not allowed inside `<wicket:child>...</wicket:child>`. See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/9e42a9548adb0da540e4e87d491f5824e778537e/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/MergedMarkup.java#L295

Why do you want to have it there ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: In the parent page, I want to pass a parameter value and show it on html page. When one button click the display area switch to child page, replace everything in that area include the span in parent page. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: One way is to move the span just before or after wicket:child and use setVisible() to show/hide it in the pages. Another way is to introduce a second child page that is used instead of the parent page in your description.